# How to display angularjs ng-repeat with json object

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I'm trying to do a search with product results using AngularJS. I've obtained an JSON object with my results": example below

```
[{"store_id":"17","user_id":"29","company_name":"Liquor R Us","company_type":"Alcohol",
"phone":"(303) 555-5555","website":"http:\/\/liqourrus.com","address":"5501 Peoria St",
"address_2":"","city":"Denver","state":"CO","zip":"80239","lat":"39.796181",
"lng":"-104.84863","mon_open":"","mon_close":"","tues_open":"","tues_close":"",
"wed_open":"","wed_close":"","thurs_open":"","thurs_close":"","fri_open":"","fri_close":"",
"sat_open":"","sat_close":"","sun_open":"","sun_close":"","distance":"1.1668156112981596",
"s":"s","st":"Every Store"}]
```

I'm using `ng-repeat="store in storeResult"` and the results will not display until I click on my Filter function, please note the filter is not applied!

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="store in storeResult">
    {{store.company_name}}
</div>
```

`ng-click="setFilter('all');"`

```
$scope.setFilter = function(filter) {
    if(filter == 'all') {
        $scope.searchProduct.product_type = '';
        $scope.searchStore.company_type = '';
    }
}
```

If I click the "setFilter" button, all results show. I'm trying to figure out how to make it display without having to click the button.

This work around only works in Chrome. Firefox and IE, never display results.

Plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/44wrLbwvQpc27ss67VIr?p=preview)

Comment: could you provide working plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: Am I missing something? 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Please you could use http://plnkr.co/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide relevant code in question itself. To demonstrate problem provide a simple demo in a sandbox like plunker , jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com etc not a link to your live version where nobody can test your code

Comment: @charlietfl - You can test the code in the environment its in. You can inspect all code you need to review whats going on. This issue, doesn't even make sense. Im just trying to display a JSON object with an NG-REPEAT and it doesn't display.

Comment: We can't edit code in that environment and you aren't providing a minimal representation of the problem. If you want help, help us help you. Nobody wants to go sort through all sorts of code not relevant to the problem to try to find your issue

Comment: @charlietfl All relevant code is provided in my issue. I've provided the JSON object and the ng-repeat code I'm using. This is supposed to be all that is needed to display the data. The Additional "setFilter" function is my work around that makes the content display. There is nothing else going on.

Comment: Did you at any point have a filter? Also, what is displayed if you put `{{storeResult}}`?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein As filters go for Angular, this is not one applied at any time. If I print out just the storeResults nothing shows until, again, I click that link which then outputs the entire object. Again, only in Chrome. Trying to get a plnkr working but it wont run angular...

Comment: For clarification, `{{storeResult}}`, the whole array, doesn't display anything, even outside of the ngRepeat loop, until you've clicked and activated the filter function?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Correct, I'm printing {{storeResult}} just above where the loop is in the code. It doesn't display until that click. I just added the Plunker code, this doesn't ever show the results but will print the {{storeResult}} instantly.

Comment: @charlietfl Added plunker

Comment: Are you assigning storeResult the same way you have it in your Plunker? If so, I think I know your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My best guest is that by clicking the `setFilter` button you are triggering a digest cycle and your `ngRepeat` will be executed because of that. I suspect that you are assigning your `storeResult` outside the digest cycle and that's the reason is not displaying initially. I cannot tell for sure because is not in your description how is that JSON assigned to your storeAssignment .

Can you check how is that variable assigned?

Can you change the way it's and do this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.storeAssignment = _your_json_value;
});
```

You will have to include the `$timeout` dependency but with this, a change in storeAssignment will be inside your digest cycle and the ngRepeat will *see* that change.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The value for storeResult is pulled via a ajax request, as part of the "setSearch" function but I couldn't run that in plunker so I just put in the string value. Which also doesn't display.

Comment: I've done this:    $timeout(function() { $scope.alcoholResult = alcoholResult; $scope.mjResult = mjResult; $scope.storeResult = storeResult;  }); And my results show. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, there's a big change that after your ajax response the variable is assigned outside of the digest cycle. Can you try my solution? Add the $timeout code on the moment of the assignment. That should solve it (you can also do a $scope.apply but I prefer the $timeout because you can run into errors with apply if already in a digest cycle.

Comment: Can't up vote yet, or I would. I found that if i use the angular http instead of an ajax call the digest doesn't complete early and the data shows without needing the timeout call. 2 days I spent on this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting the filter to 'all' until you click the filter function.  Make sure that `filter` starts out as 'all'.